# Eclipse / Aptana regex search and replace

Tags: php, regex, eclipse, aptana

In Aptana (Eclipse), I want to replace in a lot of file PHP associative array by objects :

```
$requete["something"]
```

by

```
$row->something
```

I've tried this, SEARCH :

```
\$requete\[\"([\w.])+\"\]
```

with, REPLACE:

```
\$row->$1
```

but the regex engine only takes the last character of the search : g for something

Any ideas welcome !
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the regex is only matching the last character of the group is the plus sign is outside the word match group. Also, the period is unneeded.

To fix the Regex, replace the period after the `w` with the plus sign

`\$requete\[\"([\w]+)\"\]`

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I understand my mistake. And the solution above works as well...

Answer (score 1):

Use `\$requete\[\"(\w+?)\"\]` for regex in the search portion. The issue with your current regex is that you are using the quantifier outside of the capturing group.

Comment: `\w` itself is a shorthand for representing character classes that match word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). More on character classes here http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html